# How to search a file watcher job in Control-M

Tags: control-m

I have a list of files that are processed by Control-M file watchers, but I am not able to find which file is processed by which file watcher.

How can I search for a control-M file watcher for a specific file?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the search tool to select FileWatchers.

In Control-m 8, go to Monitoring, display all jobs, click on "search" and then "advanced".

In "General" you can select "FileWatcher" in "Job Type" drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go through the sysouts I'm afraid, or export all the tables and then `grep` for the filename you are looking for: e.g. `grep -il filenamehere *`. It would tell you which table the job is in, and then you would have to go through each `.xml` to find the job in question. I've written some powershell to search through the `.xml` to pull out info that I need, so definitely an option.